# file.slice is 'undefined' in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am using phantomjs to upload a file on my web server. Somehow, I am using `slice()` function in my upload function which phantomjs is not recognizing and throwing 'undefined' exception. However, the same code works pretty well with normal browsers.

Can anybody help me in explaining the reason and any alternative?

Exception:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'file.slice(start, stop + 1)')
```

Comment: And `file` is an Array?

Comment: Its a String...plain text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `file.webkitSlice(start, stop + 1);`

Slice is not yet fully supported and Phantom is based on webkit.